# How can i solve this empty dataframe problem?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, api

I'm trying to save some API request on a DataFrame, but after running the code, it continues empty. What am I missing? Could someone help me?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

lista = []
lista = pd.DataFrame(lista)
contador = 0
data_inicial = 'https://public2-api2.ploomes.com/Deals'

while contador <= 3:
    data_text = requests.get(data_inicial, headers={'User-Key':).text
    json_object = json.loads(data_text)
    json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object,indent=2)
    data_teste =  requests.get(data_inicial, headers={'User-Key':})
    dictr = data_teste.json()
    recs = dictr['value']
    code = json_normalize(recs)
    lista.append(code)   

    next_link = dictr['@odata.nextLink']
    data_inicial = next_link    

    contador = contador + 1 

    continue
```

I deleted the header to avoid problems. But I think its something on the sintaxe.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `lista.append(code)`, it is appending to a data frame because of the earlier lines:

```
lista = []
lista = pd.DataFrame(lista)
```

Data frame appends are not in place. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html. It is also deprecated. Append to the list (which *is* in place) by omitting the second `lista` assignment, then `pd.concat`.